# Naming files using a split string

Tags: python, arcgis, blobstorage

I'm extracting photos from a FGDB file and need to name the file using part of the name of one of our attributes. Normally this script just takes attributes and concatenates them, but I need to do the reverse and actually split a single attribute at the second "-", and then use the first string as the file name:

```
from arcpy import da
import os
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fileLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID', 'PHOTO_NAME',]) as cursor:
    for item in cursor:
        attachment = item[0]
    filename = str(item[3]) 
        open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
        del item
        del filename
        del attachment
```

Here's the code I'm using. I'm a little stumped on where exactly to start with this. Should I be splitting it before the function and making it a variable, or including it in the for loop?

As you can see I'm a bit new to Python, so any pointer will help

Thanks!

Comment: A [MRE] for where you are stuck on string manipulation should not need ArcPy to be imported and used.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code but would something like this work?

```
with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'ATT_NAME', 'ATTACHMENTID', 'PHOTO_NAME',]) as cursor:
    for item in cursor:
        attachment = item[0]

        string_to_split = str(item[3]) 
        # example: 'firstpart-secondpart-thirdpart'

        string_list = string_to_split.split('-') 
        # example: ['firstpart', 'secondpart', 'thirdpart']

        filename = string_list[0] + '-' + string_list[1]
        # example 'firstpart-secondpart' (probably also want a file extension here or on next line; .jpg perhaps)

        open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
        del item
        del filename
        del attachment
```